# Inherit from Master XML View in UI5

Tags: sapui5

Imagine I have two pages which have exactly the same layout except for the data which always comes from a different model.

With a Javascript view I can code something like this using the OO mechanisms provided by UI5:

```
        +---------------------------------------------------+
        |                  CarsView                         |
        +---------------------------------------------------+
        |  - defines the page structure                     |
        |  - contains no concrete model or uses dummy model |
        +-----^-----------------------------------^---------+
              |                                   |
              |                                   |
              |                                   |
              |                                   |
+-------------+----------------+    +-------------+--------------+
|        SportsCarView         |    |         SUVview            |
+------------------------------+    +----------------------------+
|  - inherits from "CarsView"  |    | - inherits from "CarsView" |
|  - uses "sportscar" model    |    | - uses "suv" model         |
+------------------------------+    +----------------------------+
```

The *SportCarView* and the *SUVview* are actually used and displayed in the application, the *CarsView* is never used directly. So in fact it is an abstract class.

This is all fine and understood but how can I do the same (or similar thing) with XML views?

The only method of composition I am aware of are XML fragments which would let me reuse snippets for XML views in other XML views. But this is not what I am after.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When you're applying XMLViews, I think I would get the controller to take care of the model selection. This is also where this kind of logic is supposed to be happening in my opinion (MVC).

E.g.:

```
this.setModel(
    this.getComponent().getModel(
        car === "SUV" ? "SUVModel" : "SportsCarModel"
     ));
```

On top of that, you could indeed apply different fragments (as you already mentioned) or play with visible and class attributes and binding expressions to make the views appear slightly different, e.g.:

```
<Text text="{SuvProperty}" visible={viewModel>/IsSuv} />
```

or:

```
<Text text="{= ${viewModel>/IsSuv} ? ${SuvProperty} : ${SportcarProperty} }" />
```

One word of caution esp. when playing with the visible attribute. If you get the app to construct 100 fields and hide 80 of them, you may understand that it'll be quite detrimental for performance.

Comment: thanks for your sharing your ideas. I currently have a similar approach when feeding a generic view with different models. I also use the controller for that, your code is nicer though ;)  For the "visible" flag: I actually consider this as rather hacky and would only fall back to this if there is no other choice. But thanks again for your input!